# cross-domain call fails with clientaccesspolicy file

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

My silverlight media player is making some cross-domain calls on each scenerio. There are at least 3 calls in each scenerio. There is clientaccesspolicy file on each node my app reaches.

I have no problem with my app on my dev PC, but I got some reports about System.SecurityException on last cross-domain call. So I'm looking for reasons why this exception might be thrown when clientaccesspolicy file is present and available. I bet it is about client settings, but I have to know witch one to suggest them change of those.

App is developed for SL4+.

EDIT: clientaccesspolicy file on last node::

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<access-policy>
    <cross-domain-access>
        <policy>
            <allow-from http-request-headers="*">
                <domain uri="*" />
            </allow-from>
            <grant-to>
                <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
            </grant-to>
        </policy>
    </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

Could it really be clientaccesspolicy file issue if it runs fine on most PCs and fails just sometimes?

Comment: Maybe you could show your clientaccesspolicy file?

Comment: I would use Fiddler to see if clientaccesspolicy is requested by client at first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
<allow-from http-request-headers="SOAPAction">
   <domain uri="*"/>
</allow-from>
```

HTH

EDIT:

Also one other note, if the location on IIS is a virtual, you need a cross domain file on the root of the website as well as the virtual location.